# how to fix new mongoose module and nodejs - just happen from yesterday

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I just open new project and i try to connect to my Collection
i install my mongoose module like i do all the time

but this time when i try to load my simple code: (that work if i copy the mongoose module that i have in another Project(that i install 2 weeks ago):

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/money');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', last: 'string' , last: 'string' });
 var pepole = mongoose.model('pepole',schema)
mongoose.model('pepole').find({},function(err,users){
  //console.log(users[0]._doc);
  console.log(users);
})
```

some one can tell my why i have problem with the new module and what i can do to show all the documents in the pepole collection?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, you probably mean `new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, last: String , last: String })`. Note the difference between the literal `'string'` and the reserved word `String`.

Comment: Hi boaz , in the old moudule it succed to show me 9 objects ,
in the new it show me 0 object ! like it not find nothing and the collection is empty , but the collection have 9 documents!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/money');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: String, 
    last: String 
});
var pepole = mongoose.model('pepole',schema);
var newPeople= new pepole ({ name: 'first name', last: 'last name' });
newPeople.save(function(err,user){
if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(user);
})
people.find({},function(err,users){
if (err) return console.error(err);
    //console.log(users[0]._doc);
    console.log(users);
})
```